# What did I do to my file?

Tags: command-line, bash

At work, I work in Windows.   I was attempting to move a file tonight, and used this command

```
mv myFile.jar ..\myFiles
```

I realized I should have used a forward slash, but my fingers where thinking Windows.  I can't find the file now, where did it go?  What did I do?

Answer (score 3):

You renamed `myFile.jar` to `..myFile.jar`. As the file name starts with a dot the file is hidden by default.

You can use

```
mv ..myFile.jar ../myFile
```

to move it to `../myFile`

Comment: I thought I had eiher moved it somewhere unintended, or renamed it,but I forgot that files beginning with a dot are hidden. Thanks!